# matplotlib contourf() raises exception "ValueError: array is too big."

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a data set (777 x 576) with 3D contours.  This appears to be working fine until I try to place the contour under the 3d plot.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm, pyplot
import numpy

X,Y = numpy.mgrid[:len(data), :len(data[0])]

fig = pyplot.figure('''figsize=(20, 10), dpi=800''')
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,
                Y,
                data,
                rstride=100, 
                cstride=100, 
                alpha=0.3, 
                linewidths=(.5,), 
                antialiased=True, 
                )
# cset = ax.contourf(X, Y, data, zdir='z', offset=130, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlim(800, 0)
ax.set_ylim(0, 600)
ax.set_zlim(130, 170)

plt.show()
```

That is to say that uncommenting the ax.contourf(...) line causes the following exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 248, in draw
    for col in self.collections]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py", line 456, in do_3d_projection
    cedge = cedge.repeat(len(xyzlist), axis=0)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

In case this means anything:

```
len(cedge) == 35656
len(xyzlist) == 8914
35656 * 8914 = 317837584
```

Is there something I need to set to accommodate my data set?

Comment: what if you do: `ind = np.arange(data.shape[0]); X, Y = np.meshgrid(ind, ind, copy=False)` instead?

Comment: I tried meshgrid but to no avail, `ind_x = numpy.arange(data.shape[1]); ind_y = numpy.arange(data.shape[0]); X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(ind_x, ind_y, copy=False)`  The traceback has not changed, almost like there's an allocation problem.